# Reinforce Algo - Theta parametrized by a deep NN

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I'm following a course on Reinforcement learning on EDX called "Reinforcement Learning explained - DAT257x" . I m learning about policy gradient method and in particular about REINFORCE algo.

At a certain point author want to consider a gradient where theta is parametrized by a deep NN. The problem happens when applying backpropagation in a NN: we are not in a context of supervised learning and we don't know the correct labels. So the author claims that we are going to use some pseudo - labels. But how actually we can build pseudo - labels? For example: We take a certain action ( go North) what my label will be? How can i invent a labels when i'm not aware which action is good and which is not?

Thanks

Comment: The answer is likely to be later in the same EDX course/lecture. It will be a reference to the policy gradient theorem, which is a way to calculate loss functions and gradients for policy functions acting in an environment that behaves like a Markov Decision Process. Have you already seen that part, and need an answer that reviews how that solves your labelling problem?

Comment: I think that the problem is of a more fundamental kind here: You have a fixed policy (i.e. random or any other initialization of the NN). Then you play one episode with this fixed policy. In many settings such as pong or chess, every move within the game gets a reward of 0 as we do not know yet whether this was a smart move. Only at the end of the episode you then correct the weights, i.e. if the rewards are +10 if you win and -10 if you loose then you make it a little more likely that the NN plays as it did right now (multiplied by 10) if it won and multiplied by -10 if it lost...